# Heroku pukes on en.yaml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have deployed an app to Heroku. The app works okay in dev, and tests pass. 
The deployment works and webserver is running. However the following line from the en.yml file is causing internal server error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (syntax error on line 14, col 8: `        current_practice_telephone:           "Telephone"'):
```

**My full en.yml file**

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        password_digest: "Password"
    credential:
        current_practice_address_line1:     "Address"
        current_practice_address_city:      "City"
        current_practice_address_state:     "State"
        current_practice_address_country:   "Country"
        current_practice_address_zip_code:  "Zip Code"
        current_practice_telephone:         "Telephone"
        NPI_number:                         "Your NPI Number"
        license_number:                     "Your State License Number"
        state_license_website_link:         "Can you provide a link to your state license information? (Optional)"
        current_practice_name:              "Practice Name"
        current_practice_title:             "Your Title"
        current_practice_fellowship:        "Name of your Fellowship"
        current_practice_residency:         "Name of your Residency"
        current_practice_subspecialty:      "Name of your subspecialty"
```

I'm really confused why heroku server would puke here. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I fixed the missing quote but heroku still will not process the YAML file. After the lastest update:

**local console**

```
 YAML.load(File.open('config/locales/en.yml'))
 => {"en"=>{"activerecord"=>{"attributes"=>{"user"=>{"password_digest"=>"Password"}}, "credential"=>{"current_practice_address_line1"=>"Address", "current_practice_address_city"=>"City", "current_practice_address_state"=>"State", "current_practice_address_country"=>"Country", "current_practice_address_zip_code"=>"Zip Code", "current_practice_telephone"=>"Telephone", "NPI_number"=>"Your NPI Number", "license_number"=>"Your State License Number", "state_license_website_link"=>"Can you provide a link to your state license information? (Optional)", "current_practice_name"=>"Practice Name", "current_practice_title"=>"Your Title", "current_practice_fellowship"=>"Name of your Fellowship", "current_practice_residency"=>"Name of your Residency", "current_practice_subspecialty"=>"Name of your subspecialty"}}}}
```

**heroku console**

```
irb(main):001:0> YAML.load(File.open('config/locales/en.yml'))
ArgumentError: syntax error on line 11, col 8: `        current_practice_telephone:         "Telephone"'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
    from (irb):1
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a invisible character on the affected line that causes the problems. Either configure your editor to show invisible characters, or simple delete the line, and type it again.

Comment: This happened to me once when I edited some .yml.  My normal dev environment is TextMate/Mac.  But I decided to manually edit some .yml in production, (it was beta test at that point).  So I fired up the vi editor on the production environment .yml to correct a simple 1 char error.  Vi ended up replacing two spaces with a tab,   (probably inadvertently added a new line, deleted it, and in the process swapped two spaces with a tab (I set my vi tab stops = 2).

When dealing with .yml,  pay attention to the editor(s) you use and their space/tab replacement policy.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a quote after "Zip Code

But in general,  when you see this error it's because your editor has replaced spaces with tab characters.  Yml is dependent on spaces for indentation.

Comment: Yeah you're right, that was the problem...HOW the heck did this not break in DEV??!? :) Thanks for the added brainpower on this one RadBrad

Comment: Sorry RadBrad, false positive there. The original problem persists. See the console outputs in the original question.

Comment: Also make sure there are no tabs,  make sure the indentations are all done with space characters.

Comment: thanks brad. I think that's it. if you update your answer about the tabs and indentations I'll award you the answer.